# Is it possible to cancel a flag or change it?

Tags: support, flagging

I accidentally [flagged an answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/116929/177684) with the wrong reason - `not an answer` instead of `spam`.

Is it possible to change it after I flagged it? Does it matter a lot?

Comment: No harm, no foul in situations like this.  Thanks for being diligent about it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [retract a flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/21960), but you won't be able to put a new flag on the same post.

From Meta Stack Exchange:

> To retract a flag, click the `flag` link again and the button should become `Retract Flag`. [...] You...cannot retract an active flag for moderator attention if the post has been deleted and you don't have enough rep to see deleted posts.

It doesn't much matter for a single post. People who handle the flags will certainly note the incorrect flag and flag it themselves with the "correct" flag. If you regularly mis-use flags, the Moderators may have a word with you.